# android - get saved X and Y array points from xml file?

Tags: android, xml, arrays, arraylist

I'm drawing about 130 points on the screen. This points having X and Y values (Float values). Now, I don't know how to get X and Y values or how I should set the x and y in the xml file?

I made it like this. But this don't works.
e.g. The first point is: x: 100.340, y: 200.000

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <array name="myArray_0">
      <item>100.340,200.000</item>
      <item>350.450,400.900</item>
      <item>300.250,400.415</item>
      ...
   </array>
```

...

Comment: Do these points have patterns or calculateable?

Comment: No. they don't have patterns...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’ve encountered a problem similar to yours before. I don’t think Android has tools for reading key-values pairs inside the res->values XML file. 
Save the XML file in your assets directory instead of res-> values directory. Then, from your Activity, read the XML file in the assets folder.
I think the following code works. I didn’t test it. If it doesn’t work, let me know.

Inside your assets folder, you can put a XML document named “myPoints”.

```
<resources>
    <point Pointz="Point1">
        <item Xpoint="100.340"></item>
        <item Ypoint="200.000"></item>
    </point>
    <point Pointz="Point2">
        <item Xpoint="350.450"></item>
        <item Ypoint="400.900"></item>
    </point>
<end></end>
</resources>
```

In your activity:

```
Double Xpoint, Ypoint;
int PointNum;

//Call the ReadXML() method somewhere in onCreate
private void ReadXML() {
        try {
            SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
            XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
            GetXML_Handler doingWork = new GetXML_Handler();
            xr.setContentHandler(doingWork);
            InputSource Isource = new InputSource(this.getActivity().getAssets().open("myPoints.xml")); 
            xr.parse(Isource);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

//This is a private class inside whatever Acitivity u are in.
private class GetXML_Handler extends DefaultHandler {
    boolean foundWord = false;
    int i = 0;
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
            if (localName.equals("point")) {
                foundWord = true;
                PointNum = attributes.getValue("Pointz"); //so PointNum will either be saved as "Point1" or "Point2"
            }
            } else if (foundWord == true && localName.equals("item")) {
                Xpoint = attributes.getValue(0);
                Ypoint = attributes.getValue(1);
            } else if (localName.equals("end")) {
                foundWord = false;              
            }
        } // End of startElement
}// End of Private Class GetXML_Handler
```

---

If you insist on saving the XML file inside the res-> values folder, u can save the points 2 ways:
1st way is to alternate between X an Y points.

```
<string-array name="points">
        <item>100.340</item>  //X coordinate #1
        <item>200.000</item>  //Y coordinate #1
        <item>350.450</item>   //X coordinate #2
        <item>400.900</item>   //Y coordinate #2
</string-array>
```

2nd way is to save it as 2 arrays. One array for the X-coordinates and 1 array for the Y-coordinates.

```
<string-array name="Xpoints">
        <item>100.340</item>  //X coordinate #1
        <item>350.450</item>   //X coordinate #2
</string-array>
<string-array name="Ypoints">
        <item>200.000</item>  //Y coordinate #1
        <item>400.900</item>   //Y coordinate #2
</string-array>
```